# Android Table Layout

Tags: android

I want to draw a vertical line in before a textView. I am able to draw  horizontal line by using View but not horizontal line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI,
Try LinearLayout with width 1 dip and height as fillparent . or text view with width 1dip and height as fillparent.